# ColdFusion 2021 Upgrade Having Code Base on D Drive and CF Server on C Drive

Tags: coldfusion

I am upgrading to ColdFusion 2021

My current ColdFusion application has CF Server installed on the C Drive whilst all the application code lives in a WebApps directory on the D Drive

As the current codebase references the D drives in many locations throughout the code base its going to be alot easier to have CF server recognise the location of the codebase is living on D drive not C

The install wizard does not allow me to specify the location of the code base so it defaults  to being in the WWWRoot directory within the ColdFusion20201 directory on C Drive

I would really appreciate some advise on how to make the changes so CF server references the code base on the D drive not C

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the built in server or IIS or something else?

Comment: Also, if you are hard coding path references, now would be a good time to make those dynamic.

Comment: its in inbuilt iis

Answer (score 0):

Most production setups have a webserver such as IIS. In that webserver it is specified where a site's path is located. CF is wired to a site, or all sites, in order to process cf related requests. In the runtime\bin folder of your cf instance you will find a wsconfig.exe utility. Run that to add new CF connectors to websites. If you still have a previous version of CF installed, run wsconfig from that version first and remove any existing connectors, then run wsconfig for the new version to add connectors. In this way you can switch back and forth between versions if necessary.

For the builtin Tomcat server you will need to change a configuration file. This page has the following details...
https://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion-tomcat.html

```
To change the default web root, use the following steps:
1. Open the server.xml file, located in < ColdFusion_Home>\runtime\conf directory.
2. Search for the <Context ..> line under the Host block. It is usually found at the end of the file. Uncomment the following code block:
  <!-- <Context path="/" docBase="<cf_home>\wwwroot" WorkDir="<cf_home>\runtime\conf\Catalina\localhost\tmp" ></Context>  -->
3. Change the value of docBase from <cf_home>\wwwroot to the new web root location (for example: C:\new_web_root).
4. In the WorkDir , replace <cf_home> with the location of < ColdFusion_Home> . (For instance, C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion.)
5. Copy the WEB-INF and CFIDE folders from the existing ColdFusion web root to the new ColdFusion web root. Restart the server.
```